# Backtracking FamilyTree SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm currently building a FamilyTree with my database.
I found a query to build an output based on the familytree, but now I want a little extra feature. But I honestly don't have a clue where to begin.

The FamilyTree output can be seen here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/84004/family-tree-sql-query

So my question is, what do I do, if I want to backtrack the "oldest" person in a persons hierachy?

Fx: Which father is the toplevel for the ID 8?

By reading the output, I can tell the answer is 1: 8 -> 5 -> 4 -> 1

Comment: It'd be better to add your example to http://sqlfiddle.com.  The Stack Exchange Data Explorer is meant for querying Stack Exchange data exports.

Comment: Noted for future questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to do it with CTE. Something like this would work:

```
WITH SearchHierarchy AS (
    SELECT ID, Name, FatherID, 0 AS Level
    FROM FamilyTree
    WHERE ID = 8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.ID, a.Name, a.FatherID, Level + 1
    FROM FamilyTree a
    INNER JOIN SearchHierarchy b ON a.ID = b.FatherID
    )
SELECT TOP 1 ID, Name
FROM SearchHierarchy
ORDER BY LEVEL DESC
```

For a working demo: [On SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fdf4/17)